# Delphi tidhttp encoding special characters

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, http-post

I have upgraded an app from D2007 to XE6. It posts data to a webserver.

I cannot work out what encoding will send the left and right quote characters correctly (code snippet below). I have tried every option I can find, but they get encoded as `?` when sent (as far as I can see in WireShark).

D2007 had no problem, but XE6 is all about Unicode, and I am not sure if the problem is encoding or codepages or what.

```
  Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  params.AddFormField('TEST', 'Test ‘n’ Try', 'utf8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
  IdHTTP1.Post('http://test.com.au/TestEncoding.php', Params, Stream);
```

Answer (score 5):

When calling `params.AddFormField()`, you are setting the charset to `'utf8'`, which is not a valid charset name.  The official charset name is `'utf-8'` instead:

```
params.AddFormField('TEST', 'Test ‘n’ Try', 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
```

When compiling for Unicode, an invalid charset ends up using Indy's built-in 8bit encoder, which encodes Unicode codepages > U+00FF as byte 0x3F (`'?'`).  The quote characters you are using, `‘` and `’`, are codepoints U+2018 and U+2019, respectively.

The reason you do not encounter this issue in D2007 is because the `TIdFormDataField.Charset` property is ignored for encoding purposes when compiling for Ansi. The `TIdFormDataField.FieldValue` property is an `AnsiString`, and its raw bytes get transmitted as-is, so you are required to ensure it is encoded properly before adding it to `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`, eg:

```
params.AddFormField('TEST', UTF8Encode('Test ‘n’ Try'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
```

On a side note, you do not need to set the `Request.ContentType` or `Request.Charset` properties when posting a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` (and especially since `'text/plain'` is an invalid content type for a MIME post anyway).  This version of `Post()` will set those properties for you:

```
Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
params.AddFormField(...);
IdHTTP1.Post('http://test.com.au/TestEncoding.php', Params, Stream);
```

Comment: Oops
The packet in wireshark now contains

Comment: 0000   54 45 53 54 3d 54 65 73 74 2b 25 45 32 25 38 30  TEST=Test+%E2%80
0010   25 39 38 6e 25 45 32 25 38 30 25 39 39 2b 54 72  %98n%E2%80%99+Tr
0020   79
But the website displays

Comment: the above. I think the webserver saves my data as raw text then displays with utf-8 encoding maybe. Is there a way to send raw ascii as D2007 did. I cannot find all the encoding options to try anywhere :(

Comment: `Test â€˜nâ€™ Try` is what the UTF-8 encoded bytes look like when displayed as Latin-1. It sounds like the webserver is receiving the UTF-8 bytes correctly but is not decoding them as UTF-8. But this output proves your input string is being encoded to UTF-8 nonetheless. The hex output you see in Wireshark is the UTF-8 bytes encoded in URL-encoded format, which is something the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` version of `Post()` does not do (the `TStrings` version does), so I cant say why that is present without seeing the actual Wireshark capture.

Comment: The only way to post raw data in D2009+ is to use the version of `AddFormField()` that takes a `TStream` as input instead of a `UnicodeString`. But that is really not any better than using `UnicodeString` with a proper charset encoding, which I know works fine, I tested it. So the problem you are having now has to be related to something else, and you will have to provide more details about the capture to identify what that could be.

Comment: Remy thankyou for your invaluable explanations and assistance. I resorted to your TStream suggestion to send an ansistring to the server as that is what it is expecting (from my D2007 version). I had no idea how much was happening behind a "simple" http.post() kind regards

Comment: @Tony I don't think that is a real solution to your problem. `TIdFormDataField` encodes a `UnicodeString` to bytes using the specified charset, but sends a `TStream` as-is. The end effect is the same either way. Since you are sending string data, you really should stay away from `AnsiString` altogether. You are not solving the root cause of your problem, you are just hiding it instead. If you want to fix the real problem, provide your capture and we can troubleshoot it further.

Comment: I see what you mean. (I think) I am effectively sending binary data to the webserver (3rd party) which must do the encoding to display it correctly (from D2007) If I send the data to my sms server it needs to be in utf-8 to render correctly (which is less ambiguous than binary for the receiver).

Comment: @Tony UTF-8 is an 8bit encoding, so it is binary data. You have to send your text as encoded UTF-8 data. The webserver has to decode it. From what you have shown, you are sending UTF-8 encoded data, but the webserver is not decoding it. The question is why. To answer that, I would need to see the complete HTTP post that is being transmitted.

Comment: Encapsulated multipart part:  (application/octet-stream)
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="TEST"\r\n
        Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n
        Data (12 bytes)

    0000  54 65 73 74 20 91 6e 92 20 54 72 79               Test .n. Try
            Data: 5465737420916e9220547279
            [Length: 12]

Comment: This is when I use utf-8   
 Encapsulated multipart part:  (text/plain)
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="TEST"\r\n
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\r\n
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n
        Line-based text data: text/plain
            Test \342\200\230n\342\200\231 Try

Comment: Hi Remy hope this is enough for you to see what is going on. 
The first capture is with my ansi stream the second is with the utf-8 encoding method.
I am not sure at what point the 91 and 92 bytes are being converted to the left and right quote marks

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had the same problem, but thanks to your explanation it works for me now. I'm just curious - isn't there a shorter way than a combination of `UTF8Encode()` + `utf-8` as third parameter (and shouldn't it be "UTF-8"?) + `ContentTransfer` at the end? Something that I have to set only once, if all my input strings are same. Unfortunately, the docu lacks information...

Comment: @StanE: if you are using an ANSI version of Delphi, then no, there is no shorter way. If you are using a Unicode version of Delphi, you can omit the `UTF8Decode()` (the `charset` will take effect when encoding the data to bytes). Either way, the `ContentTransfer` is required, otherwise the data will get encoded as 7bit ASCII, breaking UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters. And `"utf-8"` and `"UTF-8"` are the same thing, headers are case-insensitive.